# Distributing a number over a course of time

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Hi I want to know how to evenly distribute a cost evenly over a course of time between three people.

the total cost of the fee is $160 dollars over 34 days. however, 2 out of the 3 people have been there 34/34 days and the remaining person has only been there 19/34 days.

How do I split and allocate this bill evenly amongst these three people?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  To set it up:  let $x$ be the amount each of the full time people should pay.  How much, in terms of $x$, should the third person pay?

Comment: It depends ... is the cost purely a function of time, or does the cost involve some constant (e.g. access fee; installation fee; entry fee, etc. etc.)? Sometimes, just because someone spends only half the time using the service or product as someone else, they do have to pay a larger share because they had the same convenience of the service or product the in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2(x)+\left(\frac{19}{34}\right)x=158.31$

$\frac{68 x}{34} + \frac{19 x}{34} = 158.31$

$\frac{(68 + 19)x}{34} = 158.31$

$x = 61.87$

Comment: Please format your post using mathjax.  Please see my edit.